# Postgres Recursive - Get root id for each child (and ignore bad data)

Tags: postgresql

I'm struggling with adapting the recursive solutions already posted here for this specific use case.

I have a table as follows

```
 +-------------+------------+-------------+------------+
 | previous_id | current_id | external_id | day        |
 +-------------+------------+-------------+------------+
 | A1          | U1         | A1          | 2018-10-10 |
 +-------------+------------+-------------+------------+
 | U1          | U1         | A2          | 2018-10-11 |
 +-------------+------------+-------------+------------+
 | U1          | U2         | A2          | 2018-10-12 |
 +-------------+------------+-------------+------------+
 | U2          | U3         | A3          | 2018-10-13 |
 +-------------+------------+-------------+------------+
 | U3          | U3         | A4          | 2018-10-14 |
 +-------------+------------+-------------+------------+
 | U2          | U5         | A5          | 2018-10-15 |
 +-------------+------------+-------------+------------+
```

Which has a couple of idiosyncrasy which I (unfortunately) can't fix as it is generated regularly by an external system. Specifically, these are:

- Root can be identified by `previous_id` = `external_id`; the desired  `root_id` is the `current_id` from that row
- `previous_id` may be equal to `current_id`
- Different `current_id` may have the same `parent_id`

The output I'm trying to generate from this is as follows:

```
 +---------+------------+-------------+------------+
 | root_id | current_id | external_id | day        |
 +---------+------------+-------------+------------+
 | U1      | U1         | A1          | 2018-10-10 |
 +---------+------------+-------------+------------+
 | U1      | U1         | A2          | 2018-10-11 |
 +---------+------------+-------------+------------+
 | U1      | U2         | A2          | 2018-10-12 |
 +---------+------------+-------------+------------+
 | U1      | U3         | A3          | 2018-10-13 |
 +---------+------------+-------------+------------+
 | U1      | U3         | A4          | 2018-10-14 |
 +---------+------------+-------------+------------+
 | U1      | U5         | A5          | 2018-10-15 |
 +---------+------------+-------------+------------+
```

Is this possible? I've set up an SQL fiddle with the sample data here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/58efb/6

Comment: I am confused: You said, that a root is when prev == external. Why is U1 in one row the root and in the second one not? How will I know which U1 row is meant?

Comment: Hint: find the candidate keys.

Comment: @S-Man: The desired `root_id` would be the first `current_id` where  `previous_id` = `external_id`. Hence row one is the desired root row (with U1 being the `root_id).  I've added this to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[demo: db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=db5659a3ec1ee054a2a1d8158e26bb2c)

```
WITH RECURSIVE tree AS (
    -- 1
    SELECT 
        current_id as root_id,
        previous_id,
        current_id,
        external_id,
        day
    FROM list 
    WHERE previous_id = external_id

    UNION

    -- 2
    SELECT
        t.root_id,
        l.previous_id,
        l.current_id,
        l.external_id,
        l.day
    FROM
        list l
    JOIN
        tree t
    -- 3
    ON t.current_id = l.previous_id AND t.previous_id <> t.current_id

)
SELECT 
    root_id,
    current_id,
    external_id,
    day 
FROM tree
ORDER BY day
```

It's a straight forward recursion problem:

1. The starting point query of the recursion: Getting all root elements.
2. The recursion part
3. Joining the last recursion result against the table: The last result gives the parents of the current query. So join the last `current_id` as new `previous_id`. To avoid infinite loops as in the second row, don't allow to join rows with same values for `previous_id` and `current_id`.